# Create a possible combination of start and end time of all machines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, combinations

I have a dataframe, dt as given below. Machine M1 has three possible start and end time and so does M2 and M3.

```
MID ST      ET
M1  11/7/2021 4:52  11/7/2021 6:22
M1  11/7/2021 6:22  11/7/2021 7:52
M1  11/7/2021 7:52  11/7/2021 9:22
M2  11/7/2021 4:54  11/7/2021 6:24
M2  11/7/2021 6:24  11/7/2021 7:54
M2  11/7/2021 7:54  11/7/2021 9:24
M3  11/7/2021 4:56  11/7/2021 6:26
M3  11/7/2021 6:26  11/7/2021 7:56
M3  11/7/2021 7:56  11/7/2021 9:26
```

I want to find a combination of start and end time for each machine in the form of dataframe. Like  if I fix the value of ST and ET of M2 and M3 respectively and vary M1 only three combinations possible are as below. I want all such combinations in a dataframe like df with unique ID for each combination (including the above analysis for M2 and M3).

```
Combination C1
MID ST      ET
M1  11/7/2021 4:52  11/7/2021 6:22
M2  11/7/2021 4:54  11/7/2021 6:24
M3  11/7/2021 4:56  11/7/2021 6:26      



Combination C2  

MID ST              ET
M1  11/7/2021 6:22  11/7/2021 7:52
M2  11/7/2021 4:54  11/7/2021 6:24
M3  11/7/2021 4:56  11/7/2021 6:26      

Combination C3
    
MID ST              ET
M1  11/7/2021 7:52  11/7/2021 9:22
M2  11/7/2021 4:54  11/7/2021 6:24
M3  11/7/2021 4:56  11/7/2021 6:26
```

Dataframe, df (Final dataframe will be this):

```
MID ST              ET              Cname
M1  11/7/2021 4:52  11/7/2021 6:22  C1
M2  11/7/2021 4:54  11/7/2021 6:24  C1
M3  11/7/2021 4:56  11/7/2021 6:26  C1
M1  11/7/2021 6:22  11/7/2021 7:52  C2
M2  11/7/2021 4:54  11/7/2021 6:24  C2
M3  11/7/2021 4:56  11/7/2021 6:26  C2
M1  11/7/2021 7:52  11/7/2021 9:22  C3
M2  11/7/2021 4:54  11/7/2021 6:24  C3
M3  11/7/2021 4:56  11/7/2021 6:26  C3
M1  11/7/2021 4:52  11/7/2021 6:22  C4
M2  11/7/2021 6:24  11/7/2021 7:54  C4
M3  11/7/2021 4:56  11/7/2021 6:26  C4
M1  11/7/2021 6:22  11/7/2021 7:52  C5
M2  11/7/2021 6:24  11/7/2021 7:54  C5
M3  11/7/2021 4:56  11/7/2021 6:26  C5
M1  11/7/2021 7:52  11/7/2021 9:22  C6
M2  11/7/2021 6:24  11/7/2021 7:54  C6
M3  11/7/2021 4:56  11/7/2021 6:26  C6
M1  11/7/2021 4:52  11/7/2021 6:22  C7
M2  11/7/2021 7:54  11/7/2021 9:24  C7
M3  11/7/2021 4:56  11/7/2021 6:26  C7
M1  11/7/2021 6:22  11/7/2021 7:52  C8
M2  11/7/2021 7:54  11/7/2021 9:24  C8
M3  11/7/2021 4:56  11/7/2021 6:26  C8
M1  11/7/2021 7:52  11/7/2021 9:22  C9
M2  11/7/2021 7:54  11/7/2021 9:24  C9
M3  11/7/2021 4:56  11/7/2021 6:26  C9
M1  11/7/2021 4:52  11/7/2021 6:22  C10
M2  11/7/2021 7:54  11/7/2021 9:24  C10
M3  11/7/2021 6:26  11/7/2021 7:56  C10
M1  11/7/2021 6:22  11/7/2021 7:52  C11
M2  11/7/2021 7:54  11/7/2021 9:24  C11
M3  11/7/2021 6:26  11/7/2021 7:56  C11
M1  11/7/2021 7:52  11/7/2021 9:22  C12
M2  11/7/2021 7:54  11/7/2021 9:24  C12
M3  11/7/2021 6:26  11/7/2021 7:56  C12
M1  11/7/2021 4:52  11/7/2021 6:22  C13
M2  11/7/2021 7:54  11/7/2021 9:24  C13
M3  11/7/2021 7:56  11/7/2021 9:26  C13
M1  11/7/2021 6:22  11/7/2021 7:52  C14
M2  11/7/2021 7:54  11/7/2021 9:24  C14
M3  11/7/2021 7:56  11/7/2021 9:26  C14
M1  11/7/2021 7:52  11/7/2021 9:22  C15
M2  11/7/2021 7:54  11/7/2021 9:24  C15
M3  11/7/2021 7:56  11/7/2021 9:26  C15
```

What I have tried?
I have used `combination` and `product` functions in `itertools` but didn't get desired result. I have also tried `groupby`.

```
from  itertools import product
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(*dt.values.T)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `groupby` and `itertools.product`:

```
df["UID"] = df["MID"]+(df.groupby("MID").transform("cumcount")+1).astype(str)
combinations = pd.Series(list(itertools.product(*df.groupby("MID")["UID"].agg(list).tolist())), name="UID")
combinations = combinations.explode()

output = df.merge(combinations.reset_index(), how="right", on="UID")
output["CName"] = "C" + (output["index"]+1).astype(str)
output = output.drop(["UID", "index"], axis=1)

>>> output
   MID                  ST                  ET CName
0   M1 2021-11-07 04:52:00 2021-11-07 06:22:00    C1
1   M2 2021-11-07 04:54:00 2021-11-07 06:24:00    C1
2   M3 2021-11-07 04:56:00 2021-11-07 06:26:00    C1
3   M1 2021-11-07 04:52:00 2021-11-07 06:22:00    C2
4   M2 2021-11-07 04:54:00 2021-11-07 06:24:00    C2
..  ..                 ...                 ...   ...
76  M2 2021-11-07 07:54:00 2021-11-07 09:24:00   C26
77  M3 2021-11-07 06:26:00 2021-11-07 07:56:00   C26
78  M1 2021-11-07 07:52:00 2021-11-07 09:22:00   C27
79  M2 2021-11-07 07:54:00 2021-11-07 09:24:00   C27
80  M3 2021-11-07 07:56:00 2021-11-07 09:26:00   C27
```

Comment: How to add a column with combination? Notice that index 0,9, and 18 make combination C1. How do I get it as a column?

Comment: How do you know which combination is C1, which is C2 etc.? Do you have a DataFrame with this information?

Comment: You can see in the question. The first possible values of M1, M2, and M3 make C1. Now, keeping ST and ET of M2 and M3 constant the second possible value of M1 when added makes C2.

Comment: I thought you want all possible combinations? Do you only want all the first rows, all the second rows and all the third rows?

Comment: I want to create possible combinations of start and end time of all machines not finding all the possibilities only

Comment: Please edit your OP to clarify exactly what you mean. "Like if I fix the value of ST and ET of M2 and M3 respectively and vary M1 only three combinations possible are as below." is very unclear. Fix the value to what? Explain the logic more clearly.

Comment: Please see the section of code just before dataframe,df. I have made some changes to make it more clear.

Comment: @vp_050 - I edited my answer. I think this is what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239093/discussion-between-vp-050-and-not-speshal).